# SQL query not working in alphabetical post title/content search

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I have an ajax request using wp_ajax sending one variable named "q" what I want to do is after the script get's the request to look inside the db and fetch the title and id of the corresponding posts that have either the title or the content "like" the variable so in other words here is my code :

```
global $wpdb;
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'question' AND post_status = 'publish' 
            AND post_title LIKE %s OR post_content LIKE %s";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql,like_escape($q),like_escape($q)));

            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($posts as $post){
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
```

now I have the following posts :
test 
test 2
Lorem lipsum ...
Lorem lipsum ...

when I type "te" it should get all the posts because all of them contain "te" in their title but I get nothing

on typing "tes" it should get the tow "test" but again I get nothing and so one 
but if i type the full word "test" it gives me the tow "test" posts for the other one it does not work at all .

Can you please advise me on this ? It's getting annoying ...

/*Edit*/

I have made the following changes :

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql,'%'.like_escape($q).'%','%'.like_escape($q).'%'));
```

now what happens is that i get all the posts from the db it seams like it ignores the post_type and post_status clauses

Regards,
Paul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dude, no need of the SQL mess! WP allows you to search through the post content or titles alphabetically using the [search parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter).

So, use this solution instead...

```
global $wpdb;
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
$posts = get_posts(array('s' => $q, 'post_type' => 'question', 'posts_per_page' => -1));

echo '<ul>';
foreach($posts as $post){
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Put this in the AJAX handler function. It will work!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help!