# How to modify wp_ajax function?

Tags: ajax, actions

I want to modify wp_ajax_find_posts function. It receives search string from find-posts form and delivers search results by ajax. Part of the function looks like this:

```
function wp_ajax_find_posts() {
    global $wpdb;
    check_ajax_referer( 'find-posts' );

    // ........
    $search .= " OR ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%{$term}%') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%{$term}%')";
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title, post_status, post_date FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = '$what' AND post_status IN ('draft', 'publish') AND ($search) ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 50" );

    $html = //......

    $x = new WP_Ajax_Response();
    $x->add( array(
        'what' => $what,
        'data' => $html
    ));
    $x->send();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_find_posts', 'wp_ajax_find_posts,1)
```

I want to modify the line $post to add post_author to the querry in order to limit the results within current loggin user. I would like to learn how to hook up with this wp_ajax_find_post function to let it accept my modified $post. Do I have to do remove_action and add_action to make completely rewrite of the above funtion?

Comment: Are you trying to alphabetically search the posts of the current logged in user?

Comment: I will modify the $post, add POST_AUTHOR = ...

Comment: @RutwickGangurde , I just edited my question. I want to modify he line of $post, add post_author in this querry.

Comment: But if you're trying to do what I'm assuming you are, then it can be done in an easier way!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde , How? as long as the user can search within his own posts, it will be great.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: From the look at it you would need to fork and re-hook whole function indeed, so probably not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can jump in front of an AJAX hook by specifying a higher priority (i.e. lower number), like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_find_posts', 'wp_ajax_find_posts', 0 );
```

NB: works because 0 < 1

Answer (score 0):

I've posted the code for alphabetical title/content search here: [SQL query not working in alphabetical post title/content search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55736/sql-query-not-working-in-alphabetical-post-title-content-search/55743#55743)

Now you need the author as the currently logged in user. So modify the function to include this:

```
//This goes at the top in the function
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

//Change the get_posts in the original code with this
$posts = get_posts(array('s' => $q, 'author' => $current_user->ID, 'posts_per_page' => 2));
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: sorry for my question not clear. I need to know how to hook up with the wp_ajax_find_post function to add my own thing. It's not necessary to modify the search. I just edited my question.

Comment: You mean you want to call it via jQuery?

Comment: yes, wp_ajax_find_posts is originally wp ajax function. It works with jQuery. Everything is in place, I only want to find a way to replace or filter the $post in this function.